# Concatinating values of a matching string in an arrray

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string array[2] as follows:

```
1st Array    2nd Aray
"100101"     "Testing123"
"100102"     "Apple123"
"100101"     "Dog123"
"100104"     "Cat123"
"100101"     "Animal123"
```

I would like to concatenate all elements of the 2nd array if the elements in the first array match.

For example elements of the first array that match are "100101", "100101" and "100101". So a string with the concatenated values of the respective 2nd array would be as follows:

```
"Testing123 Dog123 Animal123"
```

How could this be achieved elegantly?

Comment: What does this have to do with Windows specifically? Removing the tag... Also, you should show what you've already tried, and what problems you ran into. At the moment there's no indication that you've put in any effort yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
var results = 
    array1
        .Zip(array2, (x1, x2) => new { x1, x2 })
        .ToLookup(x => x.x1, x => x.x2)
        .Select(x => new { x.Key, Value = String.Join(" ", x), });
```

I got this result:

[image: result]

If you needed to extract the results in a different way it wouldn't be too hard to fiddle with my method to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var strings = array1.Select((s,index) => new{ s, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.s)
    .Select(g => 
        string.Join(" ", g.Select(x => array2.ElementAtOrDefault(x.index))));

foreach(string s in strings)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

If you want to concatenate only strings which are duplicates in the first array, add this `Where`:

```
// ...
.GroupBy(x => x.s)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
// ...
```

<kbd>[**Here's a Demo**](http://ideone.com/cgYuP7)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
var indices = array1.Select((i, s) => new {Index = i, Str = s})
                                  .Where(e => e.Str == "100101")
                                  .Select(e => e.Index);
string result = string.Join(" ", array2.Select((i, s) => new {Index = i, Str = s})
                          .Where(e => indices.Contains(e.Index))
                          .Select(e => e.Str));
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming both arrays are the same length, this should give you the output you need.

```
var array1 = new[] {"100101", "100102", "100101", "100104","100101" }; 

var array2 = new[] { "Testing123", "Apple123", "Dog123","Cat123", "Animal123" };

var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    // if the value has been found before
    if( result.ContainsKey( array1[i] ) ) {
        result[array1[i]] += " " + array2[i]; // append to existing "matched" entry
    }
    else {
        result.Add(array1[i], array2[i]); // add new unique value
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can zip these two arrays as they are of same size. Then group the elements by first array value.
Then join the elements.

I wrote a sample program using linq

```
string[] array1 = new   string[]{"100101","100102","100101","100104","100101"};
            string[] array2 = new string[] { "Testing123", "Apple123", "Dog123", "Cat123", "Animal123" };

            var concatenatedString = array1.Zip(array2, (x, y) => new { First = x, Second = y }).GroupBy(t => t.First).Select(t=> string.Join(" ",t.Select(s=> s.Second))).ToList();
```

The result will contain a list of concatenated strings.

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = new [] { "100101", "100102", "100101", "100104", "100101" };
var arr2 = new [] { "Testing123", "Apple123", "Dog123", "Cat123", "Animal123" };

var result = string.Join(" ", arr2.Where((a, i) => i < arr1.Length && arr1[i] == "100101"));
```